# smoothing issue with tris

Tags: mesh, game-engine, shaders, topology, wireframe

sometimes when i work with tris or i change the flow of the topology on the z axe i encounter some shading issues with smooth shading, if i decrease the normal shading it gets fixed (10 degrees) but i need it higher.
i see it happening most of the times with tris even if i see some game models with tons of tris and no shading issues ( most of the times to make holes or circles.
i dont know if its a limitation of blender or something else, here an example:
[image]
shading

[image]
topology

Comment: As you've stated, tris don't always spell disaster. However, there are guidelines for how to use them. Uneven topology (having a mix of very small and very large faces) will more likely than not cause shading issues *if the surface is not meant to be flat (i.e a large flat plane that is meant to be flat is ok, large planes on curved surfaces is probably not)*. If your case, I would try to eliminate the massive tris running across the length of that panel. Maybe try cutting the faces vertically down the middle then clean up the resulting geometry a bit.

Comment: i just played around with the mesh and notices a slight incoherence with the position of a few vertices which were causing the issue, now that the plane is flat there in no more problems.

Comment: thanks to everybody anyway

Comment: @EDOTONY Congrats on solving it :). Would you mind posting your solution as a short answer, and mark it as solved? It will surely help others. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by flattening all the faces and vertices of the side i wanted and i “mark sharped“ all the border edges